# Optimization equal number distribution

Tags: matlab, loops, optimization

Example: I want to maximize `x` and `y`

```
lb = lowerbound
ub = upperbound
a = lb(0) ub(100) 
b = lb(0) ub(50) 
x == a+b 
y == a+b
```

The special thing about this is that I need the optimization to be distributed. Explanation: x and y are houses, who need energy. They draw energy from the storages a and b. So if x takes 30 from a and 20 from b there is still 70 in a and 30 in b, but it should be equal.

The solution I want it to be is `x = 50 + 25` and `y = 50 + 25`, which would be equally distributed. How would I express this in code?

Example code I thought of but doesn't work for this case:

```
xyprob = optimproblem;

a = optimvar('a','LowerBound',0,'UpperBound',100);
b = optimvar('b','LowerBound',0,'UpperBound',50);

y = optimvar('y');
x = optimvar('x');

xyprob.ObjectiveSense = 'maximize';

xyprob.Objective = x
xyprob.Objective = y

xyprob.Constraints.econs1 = x == a+b
xyprob.Constraints.econs2 = y == a+b

[xysol,fval] = solve(xyprob);
tbl = struct2table(xysol)
```

Comment: Did you mean to write that `x==y`? If so, wouldn't the maximum be `a=100, b=50`?

Comment: You mean here ? "To achieve the solution I need it to be x = 50 + 25 and y = 50 + 25. How would I express this in code?" mh yes. But I want to maximize x and y like they are two houses who need energy and a and b are energy storages. So if you draw power from a and b there is less in them. So an equal distribution would be the best here.

Comment: You have defined `x = a+b` and `y = a+b`.  They are identical. So you need to maximize only one of them. Maximizing `x` automatically maximizes `y` as well. And maximizing `x` is simply achieved by maximizing `a` and `b`. Thus, `x=100+50` and `y=100+50`. If my understanding of the problem is wrong, please [edit] your question to make it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to say that `x = a_x + b_x`, `y = a_y + b_y`, `0 <= a_x + a_y <= 100`, and `0 <= b_x + b_y <= 50`?

Comment: I think this goes in the right direction. I edited my question a bit. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: I think you are doing linear programming. One tool is `fmincon` - constrained minimisation of a cost function?

Comment: Another option is `linprog` function

Comment: ah okay thx! But I thnk fmincon or linprog can just optimize for one variable f.e. x or y and not both ?

Comment: You need to find one quantity to optimize. `x+y` is not good, as that won't necessarily distribute the quantities equally over the two houses. But `x*y` would (compare arithmetic mean vs geometric mean). So I would maximize the product of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thats a really good thought! When I change the code to:  

...
xyprob.Objective = x * y
xyprob.Constraints.cons1 = a_x+a_y <= 100
xyprob.Constraints.cons2 = b_x+b_y <= 50
xyprob.Constraints.econs1 = x == a_x+b_x
xyprob.Constraints.econs2 = y == a_y+b_y
...

I get this error:

Error using optim.internal.problemdef.Times.getTimesOperator
At least one argument must be numeric.
Error in .*
Error in *
Error in Untitled4 (line 13)
xyprob.Objective = x*y